# Plone 4.1rc3 installation fails on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, plone

Namaste, all.

I am trying to install Plone 4.1rc3 on Mac OS X Lion build 11A494a, with Python 2.7 installed. I've tried the DMG installer and the Unified Installer and both error out. The latter's log file contains the following (which I believe is the pertinent, applicable part):

```
gcc -I"/Users/benjamin/Plone/Python-2.6"/include -L"/Users/benjamin/Plone/Python-2.6"/lib -R"/Users/benjamin/Plone/Python-2.6"/lib  -o python.exe \
            Modules/python.o \
            libpython2.6.a -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation     
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Py_Main", referenced from:
      _main in python.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

This is my first time using Python and Plone in any capacity, so I am likely overlooking something elementary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I fear this may be a bug, or at the very least an incompatibility with OS X 10.7. In this case we may be better able to help you if you email the Plone mailing list with this info. It is trying to build you a new python (2.6) but by the looks of it for the Windows platform (python.exe).

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone having tried to run Plone on OS X Lion yet. It's likely there's a number of changes to compilation settings that need to be adjusted for it to run. I'm not even sure if the official Python can be built on it or if only the patched copy Apple ships runs.

Comment: You might have some luck with the Plone's binary OS X installer. While Apple is notorious for changing their build environment with each release, the binary compatibility is usually better.

Comment: @Martijn, Hanno, and Steve: Thank you for your replies. I've upgraded to the Lion GM and tried both the unified and binary installers, which error out the same as before. Should I bother the mailing list with the contents of my "install.log" file, or wait until Lion has actually been released and more users have a go at the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this again. Unified Installer is working on Lion release with Xcode 3 and/or 4 installed.